# Eclipse JPA generator - generate equals() for all entities

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I generate Entities from Tables in Eclipse.
Is there any way to generate equals() and hashcode() functions for each model Entity automatically?

If I generate equals and hashcode functions by "Source > Generate.." for every Entity it gets overwritten when I generate the Entities again from my DB.

Comment: I'm not realy sure what you mean. But my best practice for entities is to provide a abastract base entity class which provides the id field and implementes an equals and a hashcode method. So that all entities extending this base class use the same equals and hashcode method. Often i have several base classes for createable (with id), changeable (with changedate + version) and a deleteable (with a delete flag and filter on it)

Comment: I will try to do as you say. Now I create all entity class by generator by mapping DB tables. So it create all fields, annotations etc. in my entity classes.

Comment: @rmertins 
For now I've had primary key (ID) for each table named like: user_id, role_id etc. Is that a good practise to name it all to "id" ? (In that situation I need it so I guess so..? )

Comment: In all my project the id attribute of an entity is named id. Makes the life easer

Comment: @rmertins Thanks. One more question: 
Do you generate Entities from Tables in Eclipse? Or you write that manually? (or maybe generate Tables from Entities ) What is the best scenario?

Comment: Thats more a philosophic question ;) In realy big projects where I was one engineer in a big team. They most often create first the database by there special database engineers, then they generate entities from that and then alot of people going throw them and enhance them as they want to. In the project where I was the lead I most often do first an entity model, which I let the ORM create the Database. After this I go through the generated database and enhance this.

Comment: I can't figure out how to send you a private message over SO :( I wanted to send you an example abstract base entity set I normaly use. Anyway you can find me on G+ +ReneMertinsHH contact me and I will send it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by making abstract entity class (`@MappedSuperclass`) with id field used to `equals()` and `hashcode()`.

Thanks to @rmertins